# Change color to SVG id

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

I have made an SVG image of a Cat in Illustrator. I have named my layers so I have my cats eyes named "eyes".

When I import the SVG to a developer window I can see that the layer name is there

```
<g id="eyes">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M.25,766.38c2.52,9,16.26,23.83,35.15,39.06s3
  ...
```

Now via JavaScript I would like to change the color to eyes. How do I do that?

HTML:

```
<object id="bild" data="a.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

JavaScript:

```
var catImage = document.getElementById( 'bild');
catImage.layerName.style="fill:red";
```

Comment: can you please post the code of `svg`

Comment: I want to import it like this:<object id="bild" data="a.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>  and in JS something like this: var svgdocument = document.getElementById( 'cat'); and then find the cat.eyes=style.fill=red;   something like this. I'm not great at this.

Answer (score 0):

A SVG imported inside a `<object>` or `<img>` tag cannot be directly styled by the css or the javascript of the host page.

However, for `<object>`, you can gain such access thru the `contentDocument` property of the `object`element.

In your case, that would be ...

```
let cat = document.getElementById('bild').contentDocument;
```

But, the `contentDocument` property will not be available until after the page has been completely loaded and rendered. So, you will need to put your code inside an on-load event handler.

Which, in your case, that would be ...

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let cat = document.getElementById('bild').contentDocument;
  let eyes = cat.getElementById('eyes');
  eyes.style.fill="red";
});
```